# How do I modify a value after matching on it?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm trying to walk a pair of iterators. This seems pretty trivial conceptually, but actually expressing it has not been.

```
fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
    let mut left = self.left.next();
    let mut right = self.right.next();

    loop {
        match (left, right) {
            (Some(left_value), Some(right_value)) => {
                match left_value.cmp(&right_value) {
                    Ordering::Equal => return Some((left_value, right_value)),
                    Ordering::Less => left = self.left.next(),
                    Ordering::Greater => right = self.right.next(),
                }
            }

            _ =>  return None
        }
    }
}
```

This does not work because left and right are moved when I match on them. What's a way to express this successfully?

Example (also known as *entire crate*):

```
use std::cmp::{Eq, Ord, Ordering};

pub trait AscendingIterator: Iterator where <Self as Iterator>::Item: Eq + Ord {}

pub trait DescendingIterator: Iterator where <Self as Iterator>::Item: Eq + Ord {}

pub struct AscendingIntersection<T, T1, T2>
    where T: Eq + Ord,
          T1: AscendingIterator<Item = T>,
          T2: AscendingIterator<Item = T>
{
    left: T1,
    right: T2,
}

impl<T, T1, T2> Iterator for AscendingIntersection<T, T1, T2>
    where T: Eq + Ord,
          T1: AscendingIterator<Item = T>,
          T2: AscendingIterator<Item = T>
{
    type Item = (T, T);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let mut left = self.left.next();
        let mut right = self.right.next();

        loop {
            match (left, right) {
                (Some(left_value), Some(right_value)) => {
                    match left_value.cmp(&right_value) {
                        Ordering::Equal => return Some((left_value, right_value)),
                        Ordering::Less => left = self.left.next(),
                        Ordering::Greater => right = self.right.next(),
                    }
                }

                _ => return None,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: I do apologize for this lazy example; the amount of typing I can do is limited by an unrelated cycling injury.

Comment: Would you kindly produce a [MCVE]? For example, you have two `match` statements, so it's unclear which is causing the problem. Additionally, there is a `self` parameter, but we cannot tell what the struct itself is. Perhaps the core of the problem could be removed from the context of an iterator and be expressed as just a `match` statement directly inside `main` or another small function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `match (left, right)` moves values out of `left` and `right`, so they're empty in the next iteration. So why not just move them back?

```
Ordering::Less => {
    left = self.left.next();
    right = Some(right_value);
},
Ordering::Greater => {
    left = Some(left_value);
    right = self.right.next();
},
```

Now, that's still a bit ugly. A nicer way to do this is to remove the `match` altogether. First steal a `try_opt!` - I used http://crumblingstatue.github.io/doc/try_opt/src/try_opt/lib.rs.html#1-37

```
macro_rules! try_opt {
    ($e:expr) =>(
        match $e {
            Some(v) => v,
            None => return None,
        }
    )
}
```

Then just do

```
let mut left = try_opt!(self.left.next());
let mut right = try_opt!(self.right.next());

loop {
    match left.cmp(&right) {
        Ordering::Equal => return Some((left, right)),
        Ordering::Less => left = try_opt!(self.left.next()),
        Ordering::Greater => right = try_opt!(self.right.next()),
    }
}
```